# Checkbox isChecked doesn't affect the price

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I've two different prices,
when i check the checkbox for second price,
the state show and display the second price properly
but when i press the pay button of that product with second price, it will send the first price
instead of what I've checked which was second price.
so i want increment both prices separately when i checked the check box and
it sends the specific price to the payment process

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
    getProducts,
    getBraintreeClientToken,
    processPayment,
    createOrder
} from "./apiCore";
import { emptyCart } from "./cartHelpers";
import { isAuthenticated } from "../auth";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "braintree-web";
import DropIn from "braintree-web-drop-in-react";


import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: '25ch',
    },
  },
}));







const Checkout = ({ products, setRun = f => f, run = undefined }) => {


    const classes = useStyles();

    const [data, setData] = useState({
        loading: false,
        success: false,
        clientToken: null,
        error: "",
        instance: {},
        address: "",
        mobile:""
    });


>>>>>>      const [price, setPrice]= useState(() => () => getTotal())
>>>>>>    const [isChecked, setIsChecked]= useState(false);


    const userId = isAuthenticated() && isAuthenticated().user._id;
    const token = isAuthenticated() && isAuthenticated().token;

    const getToken = (userId, token) => {
        getBraintreeClientToken(userId, token).then(data => {
            if (data.error) {
                setData({ ...data, error: data.error });
            } else {
                setData({ clientToken: data.clientToken });
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getToken(userId, token);
    }, []);

    const handleAddress = event => {
        setData({ ...data, address: event.target.value });
    };
    const handleMobile = event => {
        setData({ ...data, mobile: event.target.value });
    };

    
>>>>>>  const getTotal = () => {
>>>>>>        return products.reduce((currentValue, nextValue) => {
>>>>>>            return currentValue + nextValue.count * nextValue.price;
>>>>>>            
>>>>>>        }, 0);
>>>>>>    };


>>>>>>    const getTotal2 = () => {
>>>>>>        return products.reduce((currentValue, nextValue) => {
>>>>>>            return currentValue + nextValue.count * nextValue.price2;
>>>>>>        }, 0);
>>>>>>    };**





    const showCheckout = () => {
        return isAuthenticated() ? (
            <div>{showDropIn()}</div>
        ) : (
            <Link to="/signin">
                <button className="btn btn-primary">Sign in to checkout</button>
            </Link>
        );
    };


    let deliveryAddress = data.address
    let deliveryMobile = data.mobile

    const buy = () => {
        setData({ loading: true });
        // send the nonce to your server
        // nonce = data.instance.requestPaymentMethod()
        let nonce;
        let getNonce = data.instance
            .requestPaymentMethod()
            .then(data => {
                // console.log(data);
                nonce = data.nonce;
                // once you have nonce (card type, card number) send nonce as 'paymentMethodNonce'
                // and also total to be charged
                // console.log(
                //     "send nonce and total to process: ",
                //     nonce,
                //     getTotal(products)
                // );
>>>>>>                **const paymentData = {
>>>>>>                    paymentMethodNonce: nonce,
>>>>>>                    amount: getTotal(products)
>>>>>>                };**
                processPayment(userId, token, paymentData)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        // empty cart
                        // create order

                        const createOrderData = {
                            products: products,
                            transaction_id: response.transaction.id,
                            amount: response.transaction.amount,
                            address: deliveryAddress,
                            mobile: deliveryMobile
                        };

                        createOrder(userId, token, createOrderData)
                            .then(response => {
                                emptyCart(() => {
                                    setRun(!run); // run useEffect in parent Cart
                                    console.log(
                                        "payment success and empty cart"
                                    );
                                    setData({
                                        loading: false,
                                        success: true
                                    });
                                });
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                console.log(error);
                                setData({ loading: false });
                            });
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        setData({ loading: false });
                    });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // console.log("dropin error: ", error);
                setData({ ...data, error: error.message });
            });
    };

    const showDropIn = () => (
        <div onBlur={() => setData({ ...data, error: "" })}>
            {data.clientToken !== null && products.length > 0 ? (
                <div>
                    <div className="gorm-group mb-3">
                        <label className="text-muted">Delivery address:</label>
                        <textarea
                            onChange={handleAddress}
                            className="form-control"
                            value={data.address}
                            placeholder="Type your delivery address here..."
                        />
                    </div>


                    <div className="gorm-group mb-3">
                        <label className="text-muted">mobile number:</label>

                    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
                    <TextField  placeholder="mobile number"  onChange={handleMobile}  type="text" value={data.mobile} id="outlined-basic" label="mobile" variant="outlined" />
                    </form>

                    </div>

                    <DropIn
                        options={{
                            authorization: data.clientToken,
                            paypal: {
                                flow: "vault"
                            }
                        }}
                        onInstance={instance => (data.instance = instance)}
                    />
                    <button onClick={buy} className="btn btn-success btn-block">
                        Pay
                    </button>
                </div>
            ) : null}
        </div>
    );

    const showError = error => (
        <div
            className="alert alert-danger"
            style={{ display: error ? "" : "none" }}
        >
            {error}
        </div>
    );

    const showSuccess = success => (
        <div
            className="alert alert-info"
            style={{ display: success ? "" : "none" }}
        >
            Thanks! Your payment was successful!
        </div>
    );

    const showLoading = loading =>
        loading && <h2 className="text-danger">Loading...</h2>;



    return (

        <div>
>>>>>>            **<form>
>>>>>>              <h1>قیمت کل: {isChecked ? getTotal2() : getTotal()} </h1>
>>>>>>                  <label>نیم لیتر :</label>
>>>>>                   <input type="checkbox"
>>>>>>                  checked={isChecked}
>>>>>>                  onChange={(e)=>{setIsChecked(e.target.checked)}}/>
>>>>>>            </form>** 


            {showLoading(data.loading)}
            {showSuccess(data.success)}
            {showError(data.error)}
            {showCheckout()}
            
        </div>
    );
};

export default Checkout;
```

my card component

```
import React, { useState, version,useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import ShowImage from './ShowImage';
import moment from 'moment';
import { addItem, updateItem, removeItem } from './cartHelpers';
import logo from '../images/logo.svg'

//material ui
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import CardHeader from '@material-ui/core/CardHeader';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MoreVertIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';

import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';












import { create } from 'jss';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const jss = create({ plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()] });


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

 stock: {
    marginBottom: '1rem'
  },
  Button: {
    ...theme.typography.button,
    padding: '.3rem',
    minWidth: 10,
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
  },
  
  title: {
    backgroundColor: '#D8D8D8'
  },
  grid: {
    padding: '0'
  },
  cardFont:{

    ...theme.typography.body,
    textAlign:'right',
    marginTop:'.8rem',
    marginRight:'1rem'
  },productName:{
    ...theme.typography.body,
    textAlign:'right',
  },
  cardButton:{
      marginLeft:'1.4rem'
  }

}));






const Cardd = ({
  product,
  showViewProductButton = true,
  showAddToCartButton = true,
  cartUpdate = false,
  showRemoveProductButton = false,
  setRun = f => f,
  run = undefined
  // changeCartSize
}) => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(product.count);
//material ui
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };
// console.log(price)
  const classes = useStyles()
  


  const showViewButton = showViewProductButton => {
    return (
      showViewProductButton && (
        <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`} className="mr-2">
          <Button className={classes.Button} size="small" variant="contained">مشاهده محصول</Button>
        </Link>
      )
    );
  };

  const addToCart = () => {
    // console.log('added');
    addItem(product, setRedirect(true));
  };

  const shouldRedirect = redirect => {
    if (redirect) {
      return <Redirect to="/cart" />;
    }
  };

  const showAddToCartBtn = showAddToCartButton => {

    return (

      showAddToCartButton && (
        <Button className={classes.Button} size="small" onClick={addToCart} variant="contained" color="primary" disableElevation>
          اضافه کردن به سبد
        </Button>
      )
    );
  };

  const showStock = quantity => {
    return quantity > 0 ? (
      <Button disabled size="small" className={classes.stock}>موجود </Button>
    ) : (
        <Button className={classes.stock}>ناموجود </Button>
      );
  };

  const handleChange = productId => event => {
    setRun(!run); // run useEffect in parent Cart
    setCount(event.target.value < 1 ? 1 : event.target.value);
    if (event.target.value >= 1) {
      updateItem(productId, event.target.value);
    }
  };







  const showCartUpdateOptions = cartUpdate => {
    return (
      cartUpdate && (
        <div>
          <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <div className="input-group-prepend">
              <span className="input-group-text">تعداد</span>
            </div>
            <input type="number" className="form-control" value={count} onChange={handleChange(product._id)} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    );
  };

  const showRemoveButton = showRemoveProductButton => {
    return (
      showRemoveProductButton && (
        <Button className={classes.Button} size="small" variant="contained" color="secondary" disableElevation
          onClick={() => {
            removeItem(product._id);
            setRun(!run); // run useEffect in parent Cart
          }}
        >
          حذف محصول
        </Button>
      )
    );
  };

  return (

    <Grid  container direction='column' >
      <Grid item >
        <Card style={{margin:'1rem'}}>
          <Grid item className={classes.title}>
            <Typography className={classes.productName}  variant='h6'>
              {product.name}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>

          <CardHeader
          
            avatar={
              <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src={logo} className={classes.green}>
                
              </Avatar>
            }

            action={
              <IconButton aria-label="settings">
                <MoreVertIcon />
              </IconButton>
            }
            title="روغنک"
            subheader="September 14, 2016"
          />



          <CardContent className={classes.grid} >
         

            {shouldRedirect(redirect)}
            <ShowImage item={product} url="product" />

            <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
            <Typography className={classes.cardFont} variant="body2" component="p">
              {product.description.substring(0, 100)}
            </Typography>
            </StylesProvider>
                <div>
      <Button aria-controls="simple-menu" aria-haspopup="true" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>












            <Typography className={classes.cardFont} variant="body2" component="p">
              $یک لیتر {product.price}
            </Typography>

            <Typography className={classes.cardFont} variant="body2" component="p">
              $نیم لیتر {product.price2}
            </Typography>





            <Typography className={classes.cardFont} variant="body2" component="p">
              Category: {product.category && product.category.name}
            </Typography>


            <Typography className={classes.cardFont} variant="body2" component="p">
              Added on {moment(product.createdAt).fromNow()}
            </Typography>


            <Typography className={classes.cardFont} variant="body2" component="p">
            {showStock(product.quantity)}
            </Typography>
            <br />

            <Grid container >
              <Grid item  className={classes.cardButton} >
              {showViewButton(showViewProductButton)}
              </Grid>
              <Grid item  className={classes.cardButton}>
              {showAddToCartBtn(showAddToCartButton)}
              </Grid>

              <Grid item className={classes.cardButton}>
              {showRemoveButton(showRemoveProductButton)}             
               </Grid>
            </Grid>




            {showCartUpdateOptions(cartUpdate)}

          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>



    // <div className="card ">
    // <div className="card-header card-header-1 ">{product.name}</div>
    // <div className="card-body">
    //   {shouldRedirect(redirect)}
    //   <ShowImage item={product} url="product" />
    //   <p className="card-p  mt-2">{product.description.substring(0, 100)} </p>
    //   <p className="card-p black-10">$ {product.price}</p>
    //   <p className="black-9">Category: {product.category && product.category.name}</p>
    //   <p className="black-8">Added on {moment(product.createdAt).fromNow()}</p>
    //   {showStock(product.quantity)}
    //   <br />

    //   {showViewButton(showViewProductButton)}

    //   {showAddToCartBtn(showAddToCartButton)}

    //   {showRemoveButton(showRemoveProductButton)}

    //   {showCartUpdateOptions(cartUpdate)}
    // </div>
    // </div> 

  );
};

export default Cardd;
```

CartHelper component

```
export const addItem = (item = [], count = 0, next = f => f) => {
    let cart = [];
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
            cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        }
        cart.push({
            ...item,
            count: 1
        });

        // remove duplicates
        // build an Array from new Set and turn it back into array using Array.from
        // so that later we can re-map it
        // new set will only allow unique values in it
        // so pass the ids of each object/product
        // If the loop tries to add the same value again, it'll get ignored
        // ...with the array of ids we got on when first map() was used
        // run map() on it again and return the actual product from the cart

        cart = Array.from(new Set(cart.map(p => p._id))).map(id => {
            return cart.find(p => p._id === id);
        });

        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
        next();
    }
};

export const itemTotal = () => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')).length;
        }
    }
    return 0;
};

export const getCart = () => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        }
    }
    return [];
};

export const updateItem = (productId, count) => {
    let cart = [];
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
            cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        }

        cart.map((product, i) => {
            if (product._id === productId) {
                cart[i].count = count;
            }
        });

        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    }
};

export const removeItem = productId => {
    let cart = [];
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
            cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        }

        cart.map((product, i) => {
            if (product._id === productId) {
                cart.splice(i, 1);
            }
        });

        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    }
    return cart;
};

export const emptyCart = next => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        localStorage.removeItem('cart');
        next();
    }
};
```